# Как найти возможное количество решений в x + y + z = num?

Tags: java, алгоритм

Нужно написать метод который будет получать некое число и возвращать количиство возможных его решений `x + y + z`

Если число меньше 3 или больше 30 то вернуть 0

```
public static int solutions(int num)
```

Пример такой

```
x + y + z = 5

Количество решений = 6

1+1+3
1+2+2 
1+3+1 
2+1+2 
2+2+1 
3+1+1
```

Подскажите как называется эта тема или от куда начать

Писал в гугле по разному и количество возможных решений 3 числа и сума 3х чисел возможные решения и все такое, но ничего похожего на то, что мне нужно нет.

Любые предположения приветствуются:)

Comment: К какому множеству должны принадлежать числа x, y и z?

Comment: Перебор вполне подойдёт.

Comment: @Qwertiy перебор-то подойдет, но мне было бы интересно решить задачу математически, что я и попробую сделать.

Comment: @trollingchar положительные числа

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko строго положительные, целые, 0 не включается?

Comment: Вообще это считается несложно если подумать. Это сумма арифметической прогрессии. (n-2)+(n-3)+...+2+1=(n-1)*(n-2)/2. Но все таки тут нужно делать алгоритм перебором, так как это пример на составление алгоритма а не решение путём вычисления готовой формулы.

Comment: @coder675 опередил меня. Я уже ответ писать хотел.

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko  задача относится к комбинаторике

Comment: @trollingchar нет, без 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Данный вопрос был задан на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56398612/8992586).

*Данный ответ **не является моим ответом**. Я позаимствовал его [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56399480/8992586), поэтому я считаю, что я не заслуживаю никаких поощерений.*

Пока данный ответ является лучшим на SO. Возможно будет найдено решение получше.

Небольшое **уточнение** вопроса:

> Дается число и надо найти всевозможную комбинацию `x1+x2+x3=num`.
>   `num` не превышает `30` и не меньше `3`. `x1`, `x2`, `x3`
>   принадлежат промежутку от 1 до 10.  Решение должно быть выполнено с использованием `рекрусии`. Нельзя использовать:
>   - Глобальные переменные,
>   - Map,
>   - Set,
>   - List.

```java
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("lol:" + solutions(5));
    }

    private static int solutions(int num)
    {

        if (num < 3 || num > 30)
            return 0;

        return solutions(num, 1, 1, 1);
    }

    private static int solutions(int num, int x1, int x2, int x3)
    {
        if (x1 > 10 || x1 > num)
            return 0;
        if (x2 > 10 || x1+x2 > num)
            return solutions(num, x1+1, 1, 1);
        if (x3 > 10 || x1+x2+x3 > num)
            return solutions(num, x1, x2+1, 1);

        int me = 0;
        if (x1+x2+x3 == num) {
            System.out.printf("%d + %d + %d\n", x1, x2, x3);
            me=1;
        }
        return me + solutions(num, x1, x2, x3+1);
    }
}
```

Comment: *Пока данный ответ является лучшим на SO.* - ? По каким критериям?

Answer (score 7):

Запишем n как сумму единиц, нам нужно разбить эту сумму на 3 части, каждая часть должна содержать не менее одной единицы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Первую точку разбиения можно выбрать `(n-2)` способами: всего у нас `(n-1)` плюсиков, но последний нельзя выбирать.

После того как мы выбрали `x`, оставшуюся часть `(n-x)` надо разбить еще на две, это можно сделать `(n-x-1)` способами.

Итого получаем `(n-2) + (n-3) + (n-4) + ... + 3 + 2 + 1 = (n-1) * (n-2) / 2`

Т. е. задача решается за константное время для любых входных данных.

Answer (score 0):

Рекурсивная функция, принимающая на вход число, которое надо получить, и количество операндов:

```
//num-число, которое надо получить
//q - количество операндов
int solutions(int num, int q)
{
    if(q == 1)
    {
        if(num >= 0 && num <= 9) return 1;
        return 0;
    }

    int ans = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < num; ++i)
        ans += solutions(num-i, q-1);;
    return ans;
}
```

Comment: Чревато StackOverflowError ввиду большой рекурсии.

Comment: @AndriiTorzhkov Глубина рекурсии равна q. Какой тут может случиться StackOverflow, когда у автора q = 3?

Comment: как это работает? очень напоминает код сапера в 30 строк на js - как это работает? Может комментарии какие-то

Comment: С частным решением(при 3) конечно все будет хорошо, но вы просто написали общий случай, что неплохо, но как по мне надо было проверку поставить на большую глубину.

Comment: `q` - я так понимаю это количество переменных? типо `x` `y` `z` которые учавствуют в сложении?

Comment: Да. И да, можете отписаться какому множесту чисел принадлежат числа x,y,z c учётом num?

Answer (score 0):

С математической точки зрения вы можете отталкиваться от суммы трех чисел, что она всегда будет не больше их суммы и лишний раз не обходить по циклу:

```
public static void calculate(int sum) {

    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= sum - 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= sum - 1 - i; j++) {
            for (int k = 1; k <= sum - i - j; k++) {
                if (i + j + k == sum) {
                    count++;
                    System.out.println(i + " + " + j + " + " + k + " = " + sum);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("count: " + count);
   


}
```